# Delete a list element from a ListView

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a `ListView` which is populated using a web service. I want to delete a particular entry from the `ListView` For that I need to get an ID (a texview field), one of the elements  from the `ListView` and pass it to the database. I have an `ImageView` (a red cross) for every list element which needs to be clicked in order to delete that entry. All I want is to get the value of the text field when I click on the delete image of the same list element. I used an `android:onClick` xml attribute to call a function `deleteEntry`. But I'm not sure how to get a particular value of the ID which is in the same list element as the delete image. How can I do that?

**EDIT**

This is my adapter:

```
public class MyCustomAdapterWorkEntry extends ArrayAdapter<ViewWorkEntryBean> {


Context context;
int layoutResourceId;
ViewWorkEntryBean currentMRB;
Vector<ViewWorkEntryBean> data;

public MyCustomAdapterWorkEntry(Context context, int layoutResourceId, Vector<ViewWorkEntryBean> data) 
{
    super(context,layoutResourceId,data);
    this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
    this.context=context;
    this.data = data;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View row = convertView;
    MyStringReaderHolder holder;


    if(row==null)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
        row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent,false);

        holder= new MyStringReaderHolder();

        holder.workLogID = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.worklog_id);

        holder.delete = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.delete);

        row.setTag(holder);
    }
    else
    {
        holder=(MyStringReaderHolder) row.getTag();
    }


    ViewWorkEntryBean mrb = data.elementAt(position);

    holder.workLogID.setText(mrb.workLogID);

    holder.delete.setTag(mrb.workLogID);
    return row;
}

static class MyStringReaderHolder
{
TextView workLogID;
ImageView delete;

}
}
```

And this is the delete function:

```
public void DeleteWorkEntryClick(View v) {


    String workLogID = null;        

    workLogID = (String) v.getTag();


    deleteWorkEntry(workLogID);

}
```

It still doesn't work! workLogID is null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the specific ID value you need to pass to the function as the tag value of each "X" button in the list using `setTag()`.  That way, when the view clicked is passed to your `onClick()` method, you can call `view.getTag()` to obtain that number again and pass it to your DB function.

Comment: Wherever you are currently mapping the list data to the view.  Usually in the `getView()` method of your `ListAdapter`.

Comment: Which view is the XML attribute actually applied to?

Comment: It's an ImageView (a red cross)

Answer (score 1):

> All I want is to get the value of the text field when I click on the delete image of the same list element.

Posting some relevant code would be helpful, but here's a generic approach.

Let's assume that your row layout looks like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

We can set up an OnClickListener for the Button that reads the TextView text like so:

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View view) {
        LinearLayout parent = (LinearLayout) view.getParent();
        TextView textView = (TextView) parent.getChildAt(0);
        String text = textView.getText().toString();
        // text has what you want
    }
});
```

If you want a more future-proof, but labor intensive approach use:

```
TextView text = (TextView) parent.findViewById(R.id.text);
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you are using an adapter for building your ListView, either standard or custom,
it does not really matter.

That said, removing a list item from a ListView is in charge of the adapter, basically your 
adapter has to have a removeItem method which is gonna remove the item from the list and notify that the data set has changed.

I don't know the structure of your code but it should be something like this:

```
public class YourAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

...

List<YourDataClass> list;

...

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ...
}

...

public void removeItem(YourDataClass instance) {
    list.remove(instance);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

...
}

public class YourActivity extends Activity {

...

private ListView listView;
private YourAdapter yourAdapter;

...

private final OnItemClickListener listItemOnClickListener = new OnItemClickListener()     {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            YourDataClass itemToRemove = yourAdapter.getItem(position);
            yourAdapter.removeItem(itemToRemove);
    }
};

...

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    list.setOnItemClickListener(listItemOnClickListener);
    ...
}

...

}
```

The key is that yourDataClass has to override:

```
public YourDataClass {

    ...

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {...}

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {...}

    ...
}
```

Without knowing your code I assumed that your structure your code in a certain way, hope it
will help!

ps. I built the example using the item click listener, if you want to have a sub view of your list item being clickable and perform the delition then you need to move the logic to the getView method in your adapter.

Comment: I don't want to remove the item from the listview directly. I just want to get the value of that ID and refresh the page to get a new list